# after upgrade to ubuntu 17.04 , telegram wont be work?

Tags: telegram, 17.04

after upgrade ubuntu from 16.10 to 17.04 telegram wont work.
open with command line show this error:

```
telegram: Panic - Unable to find your tty (pts/0) in /var/run/utmp
```

Comment: Try reinstalling telegram

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh kidding me ....!!!! its not working again i was install 32bit and 64bit , but not working , cant open telegram with any version.

Comment: see comment on answer "i dont know how it's okay, but now it's okay without any problem"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also can't install Telegram in Ubuntu 17.04 x64. I downloaded the program from the Telegram website but when I double click on the program nothing happens.

The only solution that I found is to install Telegram through snap in the Terminal.

```
sudo snap install telegram-latest
```

Comment: i dont know how its okey, 
but now its okey without any problem.
also just running on ubuntu 17.04 on ubuntu default desktop ( unity 7 )

Comment: @sadegh3333 Had you installed the `telegram-latest` package, or had this problem mysteriously gone away even without doing that or anything else to solve it?